# How to CURL unsecured HTTPS

Tags: ssl, curl, handshake

For a starter I am trying to `CURL` an `API` hosted on a docker image. Here's the CURL output, isnt making sense to me.

`curl -ik -v --tlsv1.0 --cacert cfmpem.pem --key key.pem https://localhost:13443/boot/api/cfm-menu-context/?page=2`

> Trying ::1... 
>   TCP_NODELAY set
>   Connected to localhost (::1) port 13443 (#0)
>   ALPN, offering h2
>   ALPN, offering http/1.1
>   Cipher selection: ALL:!EXPORT:!EXPORT40:!EXPORT56:!aNULL:!LOW:!RC4:@STRENGTH
>   
> successfully set certificate verify locations:
>   
> CAfile: cfm.wdf.sap.corp.pem
>     
> CApath: none
>   
> TLSv1.0 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
>   
> TLSv1.0 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
>   
> TLSv1.0 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
>   
> TLSv1.0 (IN), TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
>   
> TLSv1.0 (IN), TLS handshake, Request CERT (13):
>   
> TLSv1.0 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
>   
> TLSv1.0 (OUT), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
>   
> TLSv1.0 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
>   
> TLSv1.0 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
>   
> TLSv1.0 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
>   
> TLSv1.0 (IN), TLS alert, Server hello (2):
>   
> error:14094410:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert handshake failure
>   
> stopped the pause stream!
>   
> Closing connection 0
>   curl: (35) error:14094410:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert handshake failure

Comment: Is the server expecting a TLS 1.0 handshake? Is the server expecting a client certificate authentication?

Comment: I've forgotten a lot but can you be using `sslv3` with H2? I don't think so.

Comment: Define 'unsecured HTTPS'.

Comment: @evilSnobu - yes The connection to this site uses TLS 1.0 (an obsolete protocol), ECDHE_RSA with P-256 (a strong key exchange), and AES_128_CBC with HMAC-SHA1 (an obsolete cipher).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your command line of `--cacert` specifies the trust store to verify the server certificate. You also have a command line argument of `--key`. This is used to specify the key for a client certificate and should be used in connection with `--cert` to specify the client certificate. But, you don't have a `--cert` option so `--key` does not make sense.

> TLSv1.0 (IN), TLS handshake, Request CERT (13):

This means that the server requests a certificate from the client, i.e. a "client certificate". To specify one you need to use the command line options `--cert` (which you don't use) and `--key` (which you have). Given the missing `--cert` option no client certificate is known to curl and thus no will be send to the server. This is likely the reason the server closes the connection with an error alert at the end of the handshake:

> TLSv1.0 (IN), TLS alert, Server hello (2): 
>   error:14094410:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert handshake failure

To fix this problem provide the expected client certificate and key using the `--cert` and `--key` arguments.